# Como fazer download direto do arquivo TXT

Tags: c#, html, webclient

Eu fiz upload de um arquivo em um servidor WEB, mas quando uso este código:

```
 WebClient update = new WebClient();
string Teste = update.DownloadString("http://testexxx.000webhostapp.com/teste.txt");
```

Retorna este erro: ConfigurationErrorsException: Elemento não reconhecido.

Porque ele não está fazendo download direto do arquivo, pois quando abre o arquivo no site ele mostra oque está dentro e não faz download, como posso corrigir isto?

Comment: O que seria esse seu update? poderia colocar mais código ? é um Webclient ?

Comment: update e o WebClient, vou atualizar o código

Comment: TXT é um arquivo tem que fazer diferente

Comment: Como poderia fazer? Mas tinha que ser TXT

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro é lógico que é um WebClient, dado o fato que o mesmo foi declarado como WebClient update.

Comment: perozzo, nao tinha a declaracao antes rsrs

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro sorry mate :( obrigado Rovann.

Comment: @perozzo ta perdoado :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina o header do `WebClient` para `Text/Plain`:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    url = "http://www.dominio.com.br/teste.txt";
    string retorno = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Edit:

Usando o link do pastebin:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    //retorno = wc.DownloadString(url);

    url = "https://pastebin.com/raw/xdTbdD5P";
    wc.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    retorno = wc.DownloadString(url);

}
```

> Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O erro continua O sistema de configuração falhou ao inicializar'
 ConfigurationErrorsException: Elemento não reconhecido.

Comment: então é outro problema, aqui funcionou 100%, se tiver como liberar uma url de exemplo, podemos testar

Comment: quando acessa a url obtém isso: http://prntscr.com/jo5nk2

Comment: @Slinidy Por favor, coloque o método inteiro que está rodando o código informado.

Comment: Estou rodando em um botão, oque está dentro dele é esse código que ele respondeu

Comment: No pastebin também está dando erro: https://pastebin.com/raw/xdTbdD5P

Comment: o que é isso no pastebin ? ao que me parece, veio o conteúdo do txt

Comment: Sim é o conteúdo do TXT e está igual ao site oque muda é a URL

Comment: olha a edição, funcionando também

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jo63ed

Comment: claramente não é um problema com o webclient, em uma pesquisa rápida vi problemas semelhantes causados pelo app.config. Dê mais informações sobre sua solução. Winforms, web, wpf, do que estamos falando ?

Comment: WinForms, tem o CEFSharp e o MaterialSkinManager e meu appconfig está assim: http://prntscr.com/jo670i

Comment: O problema esta no meu projeto mesmo, vou ver oque é. O código está funcionando